# form filters in zendframework 2

Tags: php, forms, validation, zend-framework, filter

I've been developing a web site using zend framework 2, I created a form with zend, and I added some filters on its inputs, but it seems they're not working. I made some researches and almost all examples I found, put the filters in the model methods, which I don't really appreciate. So my question is how to set correctly the filters and validators in the Form class ?

Here is the way I defined my Form Class :

```
class AddPizzaForm extends Form
{
   public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('addpizzaform');

        $this->add(array(
            'name'    => 'pizza_name',
            'type'    => 'text',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array('StringTrim', 'StringToLower'),
            'options' => array('label' => 'Pizza name')));

        $this->add(array(
            'name'  => 'ingredients',
            'type'  => 'textarea',
            'options' => array('label' => 'Ingredients')));

        $this->add(array(
            'name'  => 'small_price',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'options' => array('label' => 'Small price')));

        $this->add(array(
            'name'  => 'big_price',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'options' => array('label' => 'Big price')));

        $this->add(array(
            'name'  => 'family_price',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'options' => array('label' => 'Family price')));

        $this->add(array(
            'name'  => 'party_price',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'options' => array('label' => 'Party price')));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'add_pizza',
            'type' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => 'Add New Pizza',
                'id'    => 'submitbutton')));
    }   
}
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: How do you  know they're not working? I don't see any examples of it.

Comment: well when i for example hit the add pizza button , it doesn't check if the value entered in pizza_name is empty or no ?

Comment: You need to use validators for that

Comment: ok but my question was , can I use validators and filters on the form Class or should I add them into the model class ?